# Zurb Foundation Reveal modal not working

Tags: zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

I'm using Zurb Foundation 5.5.3 in an Angular JS project, and trying to execute a reveal modal. I look for this problem on community, but no solution has been successful, as I don't forget **[data-reveal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20260814/foundation-5-reveal-modal-not-working)** property or I don't want to invoke **[JS via](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21059419/zurb-foundation-5-reveal-modal-not-working)**.

This is my code:

```
<div class="small-1 columns">
    <a href="#" data-reveal-id="myModal">Click Me For A Modal</a>
</div>
<div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal aria-labelledby="modalTitle" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog">
  <h2 id="modalTitle">Awesome. I have it.</h2>
  <p class="lead">Your couch.  It is mine.</p>
  <p>I'm a cool paragraph that lives inside of an even cooler modal. Wins!</p>
  <a class="close-reveal-modal" aria-label="Close">&#215;</a>
</div>
```

It's the same as [code example](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/components/reveal.html) in Foundation docs. When I click on link, modal does not appear, and page is redirect to home.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure you're referencing the jQuery file before the Foundation? Also, are there any errors in the console?

Comment: Are you calling `$(document).foundation()`?

Answer (score -1):

You reference a similar question here:
[Foundation and AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18107201/foundation-and-angularjs)

There are conflicts in the JavaScript digest cycle when using Foundation 5 and AngularJS, so they won't work together by default.

I've used two different solutions successfully:

- [Foundation for Apps](http://foundation.zurb.com/apps.html)
- [Angular Foundation](https://pineconellc.github.io/angular-foundation/#/modal)

I prefer using the latter.